# how to display json array in angular 2 typescript front end by *ngFor

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngfor

Below is angular2 simple front end page::

```
       <table class="table">
          <tr>
              <th>title</th>
              <th>description</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let notes of Note">
              <td>{{notes.title}}</td>
              <td>{{notes.body}}</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Below is component code:: in which Note is having

```
export class Note {
  noteId:  number ; 
  title:  String ;
  body: String ;    
  color:  String ;
  isArchive:  boolean ; 
  isPinned:  boolean ; 
  isTrash: boolean ;
}



notes:Note[]=[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllNotes();
}
//get all anotes
getAllNotes(){
this.noteService.getNotes()
.subscribe(
 // notes => {   //tried not working
 //   this.notes = notes;
 // console.log(notes) },
data => {
  console.log("notes get");
  console.log(data._body);
  this.notes=data._body;
  console.log("notes array");
  console.log(this.notes);
},
error => {
  console.log("notes error");
    console.log(error);

});
}
```

in above this.notes output is ::

```
[
  {
    "noteId": 5,
    "title": "hi ",
    "body": "ragini",
    "color": null,
    "createDate": 1515820245951,
    "lastUpdated": 1515820245951,
    "reminder": null,
    "image": null,
    "collaborator": [],
    "labels": [],
    "user": 1,
    "archive": false,
    "pinned": false,
    "trash": false
  },
  {
    "noteId": 8,
    "title": "s",
    "body": null,
    "color": null,
    "createDate": 1515820746348,
    "lastUpdated": 1515820746348,
    "reminder": null,
    "image": null,
    "collaborator": [],
    "labels": [],
    "user": 1,
    "archive": false,
    "pinned": false,
    "trash": false
  }
]
```

now how to display this data in angular2 front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html code::

```
<tr *ngFor="let notes of notes; let i = index">
    <td>{{notes.title}}</td>
    <td>{{notes.body}}</td>
</tr>
```

i just did this.notes=JSON.parse(data._body); and worked remaining code is as above.

```
data => {
    console.log(data._body);
    this.notes=JSON.parse(data._body); // parsing here
    console.log("notes array"+this.title);
    console.log("Title :: "+this.notes.title);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`notes`** instead of **`Note`**

```
<tr *ngFor="let note of notes">
    <td>{{note?.title}}</td>
    <td>{{note?.body}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-simple?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Dint work gave error:ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"noteId":,. array.}]' Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:7342) at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:2550)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12098)  at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:24)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)

Comment: do we need to add import any thing

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: sorry but no ;it dint help,i posted the answer and it is running actually data i am getting from backend..

Comment: you anyway had the problem with ngFor, also you should always return the data from the api in json format, parsing to object is not the right way