# Angular 6 display data from rest api via a service

Tags: html, angular

I would like to display the data from a rest api within my angular component. I have some data from this placeholder url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. I have written a service for it as follows:

**Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class nowService {

  serviceApiUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,

    ) { }

    public title: string;
    public id: number;  
    public body: string;
    public userId: number;

  public getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.serviceApiUrl);
  }
}
```

**The component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
// Services 
import { nowService } from '../../services/now.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-incident',
  templateUrl: './service.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceIncidentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: nowService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('data is received');
    })
  }
}
```

I want to be able to display this data in a table.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display json array in angular 2 typescript front end by \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237390/how-to-display-json-array-in-angular-2-typescript-front-end-by-ngfor)

Comment: Can you please share the error that you are getting?

Comment: Here's a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4g5tj1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts. Most probably you forgot to add HttpClientModule to the providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this using ngFor,

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td><a routerLink="/detail/{{user.id}}">{{user.title}}</a></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and in the component ts.

you need to assign the response back to the variable named users. something like,

```
export class ServiceIncidentComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any; //better to have your type
  constructor(private service: nowService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
       this.users = data;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: yes you have to declare variable and assign the result